# OSX iOS- How to create .p12 for APNS from .cer & private key using Terminal/script?

Tags: macos, terminal, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am able to generate the required .pem file for Apple Push Notification Service by using the following method:

On Mac, use Keychain Access app to create CSR from Private Key and upload to Provisioning Portal and generate the required Certificate. Download the .cer file and drag/drop it into Keychain Access app. Select both this .cer file and the Private Key and choose Export 2 Items. Save it as .p12 file. Use openssl to convert .p12 to .pem

This method all works fine, except I want to create a script to automate this more.

So is there a way to use Terminal (bash script, Apple script) to create the .p12 file from the downloaded .cer file) and the Private Key stored in Keychain Access?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find the solution for this? Having the same problem here.

Comment: No, unfortunately I have not found a solution for this yet.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this on Mac, but there is [instruction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/WS144092a96ffef7cc-371badff126abc17b1f-7fff.html) from Adobe (read the second part) how to do this on Windows. AFAIK openssl cli for Mac and Window has has common interface.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this in order to get the certificates to play nice with our .NET push provider service application, so I turned the conversion process into a shell script. I'm not an expert on the tools being used in the process, so feedback would be appreciated, but it certainly is working for us.

Check the script's opening comments for the steps necessary to get it all to work, and it should spit out a usage line to you if you don't use it properly.

https://gist.github.com/misterwell/7e27d7396724580352f1

Comment: I see the script will save a step or two, but in my original question I was looking for a way to use a script to actually avoid having to use keychain access. Basically a script that would automatically generate the .p12 file without having to manually open keychain access and therefore not have to drag anything into keychain or export anything from keychain.

Comment: Ah, got it. Agreed, that would be nice!